# jQuery - getting first child div

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to remove `disabled-item` from the first child of `s-yes` - but it is not removing?

If I `console.log` the value of `show` then I see what appears to be the wrong item altogether:

```
[div#s-yes, prevObject: n.fn....
```

HTML:

```
<div id="s-yes" style="display: none;">
    <div class="s-item s-question disabled-item">
        <label>label name</label>
```

jQuery:

```
 show = $('#s-yes');
 show.show('fast');
 show.first().removeClass('disabled-item');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use `.children()` over the parent element,

```
 show = $('#s-yes');
 show.show('fast');
 show.children().first().removeClass('disabled-item');
```

Your code is not working because, `.first()` would get the first element in the element collection. But while using id selector the collection would always contains `0/1` element in it.

So while using `.children()` over the parent element. It would return the collection of elements which are the direct child of its parent. You can use `.find()` instead of `.children()` but it would return all the descendants.

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect selector to target the required element. your selector is selecting the object `$('#s-yes')` :

```
$('.disabled-item:first',show).removeClass('disabled-item');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
show = $('#s-yes');
show.show('fast');
show.find(".disabled-item:first").removeClass('disabled-item');
```

`.first()` returns the the first element with id s-yes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:first` selector on children,

```
show = $('#s-yes');
show.show('fast');
$(':first', show).removeClass('disabled-item');
//^-children,^-parent
```

Your code runs `first()` on the parent itself.

Answer (score 0):

- list item 1
- list item 2
- list item 3
- list item 4
- list item 5

$( "li" ).first().css( "background-color", "red" );

Here first returns the first list item

Instead of using

Show.first().removeClass('disabled-item')

it will return the same the error you got

So

use this
$( '#s-yes' ).children( ".disabled-item" ).removeClass('disabled-item');

.children travels only one level down as per your requirement

if the disabled-item class is in other child elements also then you
can use the first() after children

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
This is also Work

$("#s-yes").show('fast').children().first().removeClass('disabled-item');
$("#s-yes").show('fast').children().eq(0).removeClass('disabled-item');
$("#s-yes").show('fast').find(":first").removeClass('disabled-item');
$("#s-yes").show('fast').find(":first-child").removeClass('disabled-item');
$("#s-yes").show('fast').find(":nth-child(1)").removeClass('disabled-item');
$("#s-yes").show('fast').children(":first").removeClass('disabled-item');
$("#s-yes").show('fast').children(":first-child").removeClass('disabled-item');
$("#s-yes").show('fast').children(":nth-child(1)").removeClass('disabled-item');
```